# How do I specific excel for changing from $C$2 to $C$3 by draging the specific cell

Tags: excel-formula

[excel image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyPQs.png)

I want to drag the next cell which is reviews total for each city which the formula is 
`=SUMIF($C$2:$C$10003,$C$2,F2:$F10003)`
I want to change `$C$2` to `$C$3` not

`=SUMIF($C$2:$C$10003,$C$2,F3:$F10005)` when dragging the next cell for reviews total for each city.

Comment: Change `$C$2` to `$C2`. That is, remove the second dollar sign

Answer (score 0):

Have you already tried to leave away the $ signs and then (if needed add them again once the cell is moved)?

Comment: This is called an "[Absolute Reference](https://www.gcflearnfree.org/excel2013/relative-and-absolute-cell-references/2/)" (external link)